# How to get the text of a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I would like to know if i could get the selected String of a PickerView because when using the method `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` i only know the row selected and what i am using is if i know the row i know the position on the array i used to load the PickerViews but i wanted to do this `pickerView.text` to do something like this

```
if (pickerView.text == "hello"){
    doSomething(pickerView.text);
}
```

Because now i have to do much more code lines to do something like this

Sorry i forget to mention, i have 3 PickerView and to know the String is in the third picker view i have to see what row is selected in each one

Answer (score 1):

> i only know the row selected and what i am using is if i know the row i know the position on the array

And that's the answer. Don't fight the framework; use it. The framework uses Model-View-Controller. The UIPickerView is view; it *has no data*. *You* have the data, and given the row, you can fetch it *from the model*.

Comment: Yes but i forget to mentioned i have 3 picker views and i have to see rows combination but i have know i taked a break and i though better and when selected a new row i can save the String

and thanks for the answer

Comment: It's a matter of designing your architecture sensibly. There would be nothing wrong with consulting all three picker views and all three data models; saving the string each time the user changes the selection is also a possibility, but that is riskier and less "model-view-controller" oriented.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIPickerView {
    func selectedTitleForComponent(component: Int) -> String? {
        let row = selectedRowInComponent(component)
        return dataSource.pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow:row, forComponent:component)
    }
}
```

Then:

```
if pickerView.selectedTitleForComponent(0) == "hello" {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that `extension UIPickerView` i do that where??

But like i said to other person who answered i can think i can save the String in a `var` when is selecting the row i have to test this but not now is late here :)

Comment: You can put that extension in any Swift file in your project, or make a new file for it. You cannot just "save the String" when the user is "selecting a row" without **getting** the string from somewhere. The picker view only gives you the row number, not the string, so you must look up the string using the row number. My answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: Yes i know but like i said if i know the row i know the position in the array and i can save the String of that array, instead of doing what i am doing now, only looking up for the String when the button is clicked.